# how to check whether time is in between given range of time intervals

Tags: php, mysql

I want to compare a db column which stores time in format 09:30:14 against a php variable which stores time in same format.I want to check whether the time stored in dbcolumn is less than 2 miutes of time stored in php using mysql.I want to retireve some values based on this check

```
$ordertime_present = 09:32:14;
$ordertime_before = 09:30:14;

$sql = "select count(keyid) as key_id_count from key_master where orderdate='$orderdate' 
     and ordertime between '$ordertime_present' and '$ordertime_before'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "select count(keyid) as key_id_count 
        from key_master 
        where orderdate='".$orderdate."' 
        and ordertime between str_to_date('".$ordertime_present."','%H:%i:%s') 
                          and str_to_date('".$ordertime_before."','%H:%i:%s')";
```

Edit: Since ordertime_before is less than ordertime_present, it should be first in the comparison:

```
    $sql = "select count(keyid) as key_id_count 
        from key_master 
        where orderdate='".$orderdate."' 
        and ordertime between str_to_date('".$ordertime_before."','%H:%i:%s') 
                          and str_to_date('".$ordertime_present."','%H:%i:%s')";
```